# i'm trying to make a cell change color based on it cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the color of a cell blue if the last number (as a string) is one of many number I have chosen. But what I got is all the column is changing to blue not just the specific cell I want. Here's my code.

```
    Dim Count As Integer

    Count = 1

    Do
        If Right(Sheets(2).Cells(Count, 2), InStr(1, Sheets(2).Cells(Count, 2), "-")) = "10" Or "2" Or "20" Or "26" Or "3" Or "35" Or "36" Or "4" Or "43" Or "45" Or "6" Or "15" Or "18" Or "5" Then

            Sheets(2).Cells(Count, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 33  

        End If

        Count = Count + 1

    Loop Until Sheets(2).Cells(Count, 2) = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that should be a vba tag, not vbscript? You need to have the format "if x=1 or x=2 or x=3".

Comment: Any reason we're doing this in code and not with Excel's built-in conditional formatting rules?

Comment: @SJR it can't be if x=1 because these number are part of a label so i think they should be consider as txt ... right?

Comment: What I mean is that you can't write if x="1" or "2" you must write if x="1" or x="2", I'm not making a point about the quotes. Please update your tags. And use CF as Selkie suggests.

Comment: @Selkie it's simple!! i do this for a user and this user won't do it for the 63 files that contain 4700-ish line

Comment: @SJR oh i see tnx

Comment: You can use format painter across workbooks - IE grabbing the conditional formatting off of workbook A, and applying it to workbook B. I suspect using format painter along with however you plan on cycling through workbooks would be more efficient. Double click on format painter to keep it selected.

Comment: @Selkie this is .... well a good idea!! i didn'T thought of that solution!! tnx!!

Comment: @Selkie what i want to do whit the excel file is import an sheet from another workbook, then apply the changes and finally returning the sheet from where it came! does the format painter will be affected each time the user import a sheet or will he have to remake the rules each time?

Comment: I mean, that should work - but why not just directly apply the painting to the workbook you're editing?

Comment: well i wanted to make the workbook i'm editing as a tool that everybody could use depending of their needs (since the people who'll be using my tool will work with the same data) i thought i could make the tool universal enough.... at the end, sometime the simplest solution is the best ! tnx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a regular expression instead of a lengthy OR statement. I have assumed from your code the number at the end of the string is preceded by a dash.

Sub colorBlue()

```
   Dim regex As Object
   Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

   'match 10,2,20,26,3,35,36,4,43,45,6,15,18,5
   With regex
     .Global = True
     .MultiLine = False
     .pattern = "(-)(2|3|4|5|6|10|15|18|20|26|35|36|43|45)$"
   End With

   Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
   Dim row, lastrow As Long
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

   lastrow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   For row = 1 To lastrow
     Set cell = ws.Range("B" & row)
     If regex.test(cell.Value) Then
         cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
     End If
   Next row

 End Sub
```

For more info see the docs for [Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/Excel/object-model) and [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

Comment: wow! this is way cleaner that what i expected!! it worked perfectly! tnx. and, btw, how did you mastered vb? i mean i was put on this project last monday and i'm strugling with it and since you code is way cleanner than mine, if you have any advice, i would be glad to have some (p.s. before last monday i never touched vb before)

Comment: @alexilas No easy way I'm afraid, just a lot of practice ! Note I changed my code to use a row counter rather than usedrange. It didn't scan column B if your column A was empty.

Comment: well tnx for your exemple!! i'll study it to see what information i can gather for futur code!